# Anti SQL Injection em datas

Tags: php

Estou com um problema e não sei como resolver, uso essa função para validar o recebimento de algumas variáveis:

```
  if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
```

As variáveis estão sendo tratadas assim:

```
$IdCategoria = GetSQLValueString($_POST['IdCategoria'],"int");
$IdUnicoop   = GetSQLValueString($_POST['IdUnicoop'], "int");
$Palavra     = GetSQLValueString('%'.$_POST['Palavra'].'%',"text");
```

Gostaria de fazer o tratamento para algumas datas que tenho, elas estão sendo recebidas assim:

```
$DtInicial   = $_POST['DtInicial'];
$DtFinal     = $_POST['DtFinal'];
```

Comment: Deu algum problema em: `$DtInicial = GetSQLValueString($DtInicial, 'date');` ?

Comment: Apesar dos exemplos da pergunta indicada serem completamente diferentes do seu código, é o caso de refatorar sua idéia original com os conceitos das respostas de lá. Se o problema é só converter as datas para o formato do MySQL, creio que já temos postagem neste sentido também. Sobre a questão das datas, se quiser elaborar melhor, com exemplos dos dados entrados, aí talvez fique o suficiente para reabertura.